# Python regex: Including whitespace inside character range

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a regular expression that matches alphabets, numbers, _ and - (with a minimum and maximum length).

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100}$
```

I want to include whitespace in that set of characters.

According to the Python documentation:

> Character classes such as \w or \S are also accepted inside a set.

So I tried:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]{3,100}$
```

But it gives bad character range error. How can I include whitespace in the above set?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is not the `\s` but the `-` which indicates a character range, unless it is at the end or start of the class. Use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]{3,100}$
```

Comment: Thanks m.buettner. Position of - was the problem

Answer (score 3):

`^[-a-zA-Z0-9_\s]{3,100}`

`_-\s` was interpreted as a range. A dash representing itself has to be the first or last character inside [...]

Comment: Thanks dda. The problem was indeed the position of -

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track, Add a second backslash to escape the slash, because the backslash is an escape character.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\s]{3,100}$
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, @david-lai. I think this answer is inaccurate in that it doesn't solve the problem; despite working around the reported error. It might be better to remove your answer, imo.