# Regex for multiple different words, between white spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, anki

I am completely new to regex.
I just want to know whether this is possible.(I'm sorry if the explanation is confusing or too complicated)
Say, I just want to find and replace this particular heading in bold:

> "As discussed in chapter 1, the users of financial statements can be categorised as resource provider. **(space)(space)Users and decision making(space)(space)** An example for this. **(space)(space)Nature and purpose of financial analysis(space)(space)** We have identi fied that financial analysis mvolves expressing reported numbers in financial statements in relative terms. "

to this :

> "As discussed in chapter 1, the users of financial statements can be categorised as resource provider.
>   
> **(new line) Users and decision making (tab space)** An example for this.
>   
> **(new line) Nature and purpose of financial analysis (tab space)** We have identi fied that financial analysis mvolves expressing reported numbers in financial statements in relative terms. "

As my knowledge of regex is currently limited, I try to break it down to 2 parts :

> 1. to find ". **(space)(space)Nature**" :
>   
> [(.)]\s\s[(A-Z)]\w+ 
>   
> to \n$&
>
> 2. to find  "**analysis(space)(space)** We" :
>   
> **[(a-z)]\w+\s\s[(A-Z)]**
>   
> to ??

So, my question is that is it possible to just define 1 regex for 

. **(space)(space)Users and decision making(space)(space)** An

. **(space)(space)Nature and purpose of financial analysis(space)(space)** We

 and replace it with the example above?

Thank you!

> PS. The reason behind this weird editing is to upload this to anki flashcard software as txt without further editing. 
>   
> My current method can be quite taxing if I were to edit the whole text from a thick textbooks (which can contain more than 1000 editing per chapter x20 or so chapters x5 textbooks and more). 
> fyi, in anki and several other flashcard softwares, tab is the field separator between the front/question and the back/answer. 
>   
> The double space[ ][ ] is used to separate specific heading from the single space when using find and replace; which has been pre-set by myself beforehand.
>   
> The new line (\n) is for adding new separate flashcards. 
>   
> Anki (and several other flashcard softwares)  supports html so I usually added multiple cards by copying the text from pdf using notepad++ and regex find and replace several heading or first word of a sentence to suit with the question/front part of anki flashcard while the rest becomes the answer part; and then import it to anki.
>   If it is possible to automate all the finding part, I can save a helluva lot of time!

Comment: What language or tool are you using?  I think your correct answer will be dependent on this.

Comment: Something like this: `[ ]{2}` ? https://regex101.com/r/nR0xC8/1 If I understand your problem correctly, two consecutive spaces shall be replaced with a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Still experimenting with regexr, notepad++, vim (i dont know how to use this), jsfiddle but I am open to any other editor.

Comment: I think you need [this](https://regex101.com/r/xA5oH5/1).

Comment: @Jan have tried to simplify everything to the kind of solution you are proposing before, but it is just not fast enough.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you for the suggestion! but if I do that, the whole heading is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and tinkering for a while, I think I finally find the answer! :D 
 **[ ]{2,}([A-Z])[\w ]{1,}[ ]{2,}**

replace with

**\n$&\t\t**

http://regexr.com/3db4o

Drawing inspiration from :

[Regex for multiple words split by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204543/regex-for-multiple-words-split-by-spaces)

[Python regex: Including whitespace inside character range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142440/python-regex-including-whitespace-inside-character-range)

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html
and @Jan's answer

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to match word combinations srarting with an uppercase letter, having one space in-between the words, and enclosed with two space chunks.

Here is a regfex that satisfies these conditions:

```
/[^\S\r\n]{2,}[A-Z]\w*(?:[^\S\r\n]\w+)*[^\S\r\n]{2,}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG2eJ6/1) (to replace with `\n$&\t\t`)

Note that `[\w ]{1,}` will match a word character or a space 1+ times and can allow more than 1 space in between words. However, it might be good if you need to match the *last* 2-space chunk on a line. Note that you would need to add a `+` after the second `[^\S\r\n]` in the pattern above.